# AttributeError 'Nonetype' object has no attribute. But i check for Nonetype

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nonetype

I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`

So I added `if clist is not None:` But I keep getting the same error. Why?

```py
if clist is not None:
    result = [
        [name, clist.rstrip()] 
        for name, clist in zip(
            fragments[::group_count+1],
            fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
        )
    ]
```

Full traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [85], in <module>
    120             fragments = fragments[1:]
    121         if clist is not None:
--> 122             result = [
    123                 [name, clist.rstrip()] 
    124                 for name, clist in zip(
    125                     fragments[::group_count+1],
    126                     fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
    127                 )
    128             ]

Input In [85], in <listcomp>(.0)
    120             fragments = fragments[1:]
    121         if clist is not None:
    122             result = [
--> 123                 [name, clist.rstrip()] 
    124                 for name, clist in zip(
    125                     fragments[::group_count+1],
    126                     fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
    127                 )
    128             ]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: It's not clist. One of the elements of fragments must be None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

Clist out of the list comprehension is not None But Some of the value inside fragments in None, THis is why you get this error.

You need to add `if clist is not None inside list comprehension` like Below.

```py
result = [[name, clist.rstrip()] for name, clist in zip(
            fragments[::group_count+1],
            fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
        ) if clist is not None]
```

Comment: If you got any other errors then let me know in the comment.